# Load one page with parent and child pages

Tags: custom-field, pages, page-template, child-pages

Given I have a pretty long page and I don't want the user to insert content in the back-end all at once.
More specifically, this given page is made of several sections (I'm actually using fullPage.js) and so I believe I can seperate each section into a child page, giving the user an easier (or less packed) layout to deal with in the back-end.

My question is, assuming having a parent page and child pages for this purpose is a correct choice, how to load everything together in a single page?
Also, I'm depending heavily on custom fields (Advanced Custom Fields plugin), so how may I assign specific custom fields to each parent and child pages? (I'm not completely sure what's the difference between page templates and page types, I can see both options in the Advanced Custom Fields location tab)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using this in this way.

I use ACF for pretty much everything outside of a basic content area.  I'd recommend either using the tabs system or, probably more preferably, the [Flexible Content add-on](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/) (it used to be an add-on, but is now part of ACF Pro).  You can minimize/hide the flexible content sections really easily, and it won't add to the confusion when editing.

Also, all your child pages will exist separately at their own at their own URL, which could end up giving you way more of a headache.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at Flexible Content but I don't think it will help me much, because the page layout is pretty rigid and I don't want the user/client to be able to reorder content in any way.
You're right about the separate URLs though, that's one of the things that keeps messing with my plans.

Comment: If you don't want them to change the order of things, then I'd recommend using the tab system to keep things organized in a specific way, otherwise, we find our clients usually like having that extra flexibility.